# Program should work but still ends up in segmentation fault

Tags: c

So have been trying and figuring out why my code doesn't want to work with me. Cannot find the mistake here.. It should let me enter all the details and afterwards display everything from arrays. But different things i have tried and still end up in the segmentation fault. Im relativly new in programming so criticism is allowed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)

{
    int j, n;
    int *A,*B, *H;
    double const e = 2.71828183;
    int x[15];
    float y[15];

    printf("\n");
    printf("  sqrt(x)*sin(1/x)\n");
    printf("y=-------------\n");
    printf("    (x+e^x)   \n\n");

    int i=0;
    while((*A)>*(B));
    {
        printf("Enter A :\n");
        scanf("%d", A);
        printf("Enter B :\n");
        scanf("%d", B);

        if((*A)>(*B))
        {
            printf("enter sometthing that.....\n");
        }
     i++;
     } 


    do
    {
        printf("Enter H:\n");
        scanf("%d", H);

        if((*H)<15)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }

        while((*H)>15)
        {
            printf("H is wrong, try again\n");
        }   
            j++;
    }   
    while((*H)>15);

    do
    {  
        x[i+1]=(x[i]+(i+1)*(*H));       
        y[i]=(sqrt(x[i])*sin(1/x[i]))/(x[i]+(pow(e,x[i])));
        i++;
        n=i-1;
    }   
    while (x[i]<=(*B));

    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
        printf("X    |    Y\n");
        {
            printf("%d   |   %f\n", x[i], y[i]);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not allocating any memory with the pointers.

Comment: Set some breakpoints first and find out exactly where it is that you get a segfault.

Answer (score 5):

These pointers are uninitialised so they point to random memory locations.

```
int *A,*B, *H;
```

Here you are dereferencing uninitialised pointers (undefined behaviour -> segmentation fault)

```
while((*A)>*(B));
```

I would recommend declaring variables like :

```
int A=1, B=0, H;
```

modify the while loop (based on initial values of A, B it will execute at least once) (or use `do while`):

```
while(A > B)
```

and scan like this :

```
scanf("%d", &A);
```

Comment: do
 {  
  y[i]=(sqrt(x[i])*sin(1/x[i]))/(x[i]+(pow(e,x[i])));
  x[i+1]=(x[i]+(i+1)*H);  
  i++;
  n=i-1;
 } 
 while (x[i]<B);

Comment: Do you get segmentation fault in that line too ? If so, change the while loop to `while (x[i] <= B && i < 14);`

Comment: No it was a mistake, wrong line entered, my bad. The lines where the segmentation fault is coming is here, but to me these look good: do
 {  
  y[i]=(sqrt(x[i])*sin(1/x[i]))/(x[i]+(pow(e,x[i])));
  x[i+1]=(x[i]+(i+1)*H);  
  i++;
  n=i+1;
 }

Comment: same as my previous comment. `x` and `y` arrays have size 15 and start from 0. Make sure you are not accessing elements beyond that offset. You have `x[i+1]` in the `do while` loop so the max value `i` can take is 13.